# Relation between hyperbolic plane and its definition?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

I am reading a book that states a hyperbolic plane is a quadratic module with a basis of two vectors $x, y$ that are isotropic and such that the associated symmetric bilinear form on $x, y \neq 0.$ That is, $x.y \neq 0.$ However, why is this called a hyperbolic plane?

This may be a very general question but how do the conditions specified in the definition affect the 'visualization' of the vector space? Is it related at all to the geometry of a hyperbola? Any answers are appreciated, thank you.

Relevant information: A quadratic module is a pair $(V, Q)$ such that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a field of characteristic $\neq 2$ and $Q: V \rightarrow F$ is such that $Q(ax) = a^2Q(x)$ and the map $Q(x + y) - Q(x) - Q(y)$ is bilinear. The map is denoted as $x.y = Q(x + y) - Q(x) - Q(y).$ Furthermore, an isotropic vector is a vector such that $x.x = 0.$

Comment: What is a 'quadratic module' and 'isotropic' vectors?

Comment: @Berci I edited to explain

Comment: Most of this terminology appeared first in German. The viewpoint you use is credited to Ernst Witt (1936). He does distinguish the plane with  quadratic form $2xy,$ but I don't see a name for it. I'm going to guess that the word hyperbolic refers to the fact that the quadratic form $2xy$ is equivalent, over the reals, to a multiple of $x^2 - y^2.$

Comment: By the way, the term "hyperbolic plane" is used ambiguously in mathematics: one way is the one described in your post and the answer of @WillJagy; and another, imcompatible way is the the one which fits under the math.stackexchange tag (hyperbolic-geometry). So, your question really has nothing to do with (hyperbolic-geometry). Click on that tag to see what it is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit long for a comment. In 2005, T.Y. Lam published *Introduction to Quadratic Forms over Fields.* On page 9 is Theorem 3.2. Then page 10 begins with

> The isometry class of a 2-dimensional quadratic space satisfying the
>   conditions in Theorem 3.2 is called the "hyperbolic plane" (presumably
>   because the graphs of the equations $X_1 X_2 = d$ are called
>   hyperbolas).

[image]
[image]