# An interesting characterization of a hyperbolic plane

Tags: vector-spaces, soft-question, inner-products, hyperbolic-geometry

from Irving Kaplansky's "Linear Algebra and Geometry a second course." Page 19.

Theorem: Let $V$ be a nonsingular two dimensional inner product space over a field of characteristic not equal to $2$, and assume that $V$ contains a vector $x$ such that $(x,x)=0$. Then we can diagonalize $V$ so that the matrix of it's inner product has diagonal entries $(1,-1)$.

The author goes on to write that that an inner product space $V$ is called a hyperbolic plane if it satisfies the hypothesis of the theorem above.

This definition of a hyperbolic plane in terms of the existence of a null vector is new to me. My question is meant to be open ended and not too specific, but I was wondering if anyone could expand on this definition of the hyperbolic plane, and really just give me any insights what-so-ever. Thank you!

Comment: This is not the _hyperbolic plane_ of hyperbolic geometry, but an ordinary plane with a Minkowski-signature metric. It happens there's an isometric embedding of the plane of hyperbolic geometry into a Minkowski-signature metric in _three_-space, but that looks like a separate issue.

Comment: See the related discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905123/whats-the-connection-between-hyperbolic-inner-product-spaces-and-the-hyperbol?rq=1).

Comment: And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2764187/relation-between-hyperbolic-plane-and-its-definition?rq=1)